# How to eleminate variables based on comparison of specific rows

Tags: r, statistics, rows

I have data that contains twelve rows and more than 500 variables
I want to keep only the variables that have value of line 9 > 5* value of line 10

Example of data:

```
       Name   ClassType    Col1   Col2   Col3     
       ---------------------------------------
        A      Class1       10     50    12        
        B      Class2        7     20    12
        C      Class1        8     12     8
        D      Class1        9     14    17
        E      Class2        3     15    14
        F      Class2       10     15    16
        G      Class2       12     22    15
        H      Class1       10     28    10
        I       NA          50     10    30
        J       NA           8      5     2
```

Result I want: delete of column 2 because the value of line 9 in that column is < 5* value of line 10 of the same column:

```
      Name   ClassType    Col1   Col3     
      -------------------------------
        A      Class1       10    12        
        B      Class2        7    12
        C      Class1        8     8
        D      Class1        9    17
        E      Class2        3    14
        F      Class2       10    16
        G      Class2       12    15
        H      Class1       10    10
        I       NA          50    30
        J       NA           8     2
```

I tried if condition but it didn't give me good results, but I want to know if there's any other way.

The code i tried

```
data_4 <- as.data.frame(data_3[,1, drop=FALSE])


for (i in 2:640) {
  a = as.numeric(data_3[9,i])
  b = as.numeric(data_3[10,i])
  print(b)
  c = as.numeric(b*5)
  
  if(a > c) {
    data_4 <- cbind(data_4[, , drop=FALSE], data_3[ ,i,drop=FALSE])
    
    
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no line 11 in your data! :-)

Comment: can you show us the code that you tried?

Comment: Thank you for your rmark Paul , i just edited my question

Comment: Thank you Mr Ben for your comment , i edited my question and i added the code i tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `select` to select the `character` columns and the `numeric` columns where the condition matches - 9th element of the column is greater than 5 times the `last` value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::select(where(is.character),
       where(~ is.numeric(.x) && nth(., 9) >  5 * last(.) ))
```

-output

```
df1
    Name ClassType Col1 Col3
1     A    Class1   10   12
2     B    Class2    7   12
3     C    Class1    8    8
4     D    Class1    9   17
5     E    Class2    3   14
6     F    Class2   10   16
7     G    Class2   12   15
8     H    Class1   10   10
9     I      <NA>   50   30
10    J      <NA>    8    2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J"), ClassType = c("Class1", "Class2", "Class1", "Class1", 
"Class2", "Class2", "Class2", "Class1", NA, NA), Col1 = c(10L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 50L, 8L), Col2 = c(50L, 20L, 12L, 
14L, 15L, 15L, 22L, 28L, 10L, 5L), Col3 = c(12L, 12L, 8L, 17L, 
14L, 16L, 15L, 10L, 30L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Than k you, I tried your answer but it didn't work , it keeps the same data ?

Comment: @Scienceslover It did worked for me.  I updated with the data I used

Comment: @Scienceslover if you want to change the original object, assign back (`df1 <- df1 %>%..`

Comment: Yes i just saw your updated answer , it worked, thank you very much

Comment: Yes i just did , thank you very much

Comment: @akrun. Master could you please check why this does not work? I want to flag the cell with 9999:  `df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("col"), ~ifelse(. > lag(.)*5, 9999, .)))`

Comment: @TarJae I think the OP wanted to only compare the last two rows of numeric columns, instead of all the rows with `lag`.  I guess

Comment: ok. thank you master!

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, using `janitor::remove_empty`, that will remove all columns that `mutate` before converted to columns of `NA`'s:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
  ClassType = c("Class1","Class2",
                "Class1","Class1","Class2","Class2","Class2",
                "Class1",NA,NA),
  Col1 = c(10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 50L, 8L),
  Col2 = c(50L, 20L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 22L, 28L, 10L, 5L),
  Col3 = c(12L, 12L, 8L, 17L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 10L, 30L, 2L)
)

df %>% 
 mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if (nth(.,9)<5*nth(.,10)) {NA} else {.x})) %>% 
 janitor::remove_empty(which = "cols")  

#>    Name ClassType Col1 Col3
#> 1     A    Class1   10   12
#> 2     B    Class2    7   12
#> 3     C    Class1    8    8
#> 4     D    Class1    9   17
#> 5     E    Class2    3   14
#> 6     F    Class2   10   16
#> 7     G    Class2   12   15
#> 8     H    Class1   10   10
#> 9     I      <NA>   50   30
#> 10    J      <NA>    8    2
```